# Apache Pig: Add one field dataset to another one as a new column

Tags: apache-pig

Let's say we have this scenario:

dataset1.csv :

```
datefield
field11, field12, field13
field21, field22, field23
field31, field32, field33
```

What is the best way to get this?:

```
field11, field12, field13, datefield
field21, field22, field23, datefield
field31, field32, field33, datefield
```

I tried to generate one dataset (relation1) with just this columns (after loading and generating):

```
field11, field12, field13
field21, field22, field23
field31, field32, field33
```

another one (relation2) with just this column (after loading and generating):

```
datefield
```

and then doing this:

finalResult = FOREACH dataset1 GENERATE UDFFunction1(relation1::f1) as firstFields, UDFFunction2(relation2::f2) as lastField

But I'm getting '**A column needs to be projected from a relation for it to be used as a scalar**'

The problem is with the second field (the one with the datefield).

I would like to avoid joins, since it would be a little messy workaround.

Any suggestions?

Please, forget my UDF functions. They just format the input Tuples accordingly.

Adding the pig script:

```
register 's3://bucketName/lib/MyJar.jar';

define ParseOutFilesUDF packageName.ParseOutFiles;

define FormatTimestartedUDF packageName.FormatTimestarted;

outFile = LOAD 's3://bucketName/input/' USING PigStorage ('|');

--This UDF just reformat each tuple, adding a String to each Tuple and returning a new one. 
resultAll = FOREACH outFile GENERATE ParseOutFilesUDF(*) as initial;

--load the same csv again to get the TIMESTARTED field
timestarted = LOAD 's3://bucketName/input/' USING PigStorage ('|') as f1;

--filter to get only one record, which is somth like TIMESTARTED=20160101
filetered = FILTER timestarted BY (f1 matches '.*TIMESTARTED.*');

timestarted = foreach filetered GENERATE $0 as fechaStarted;

-- the FormatTimestartedUDF just gets ride of 'TIMESTARTED=' in order to get the date '20160101'
in this FOREACH sentence is where it fails with the 'A column needs to be projected...'
finalResult = FOREACH outFile GENERATE f1, FormatTimestartedUDF(timestarted) as f2;
STORE finalResult INTO 's3://bucketName/output/';
```

Comment: Does both datasets have same number of rows? What are the values in datafield? Is it a single value or multiple values? If it is multiple what is the rule for merge?

Comment: The input dataset is just one: dataset1.csv   with the four rows within. First record is the field with 'datefield' value, and then three more rows with 'field11', 'field12'... and so on.

Comment: 'datefield' is the value itself. It's  a single value.

Comment: can you post your entire pigscript?Don't you want all the fields from relation 1?

Comment: sure. Post edited with the pig script

Comment: outfile doesn't have f1 and timestarted is not a field but a relation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the error because you are referencing f1 which doesn't exist in outfile and timestarted is a relation and not a field.Also you should be using the field in resultALL and filtered.

```
outFile = LOAD 's3://bucketName/input/' USING PigStorage ('|');
resultAll = FOREACH outFile GENERATE ParseOutFilesUDF(*) as initial;

timestarted = LOAD 's3://bucketName/input/' USING PigStorage ('|') as f1;
filtered = FILTER timestarted BY (f1 matches '.*TIMESTARTED.*');

finalResult = FOREACH resultALL GENERATE resultAll.initial, FormatTimestartedUDF(filtered.$0);
STORE finalResult INTO 's3://bucketName/output/';
```